# Связь асинхронного фреймворка vkbottle с Django3

Tags: python-3.x, django, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

#### Требуется связать [vkbottle](https://github.com/timoniq/vkbottle) и [django3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/) для интеграций бота с сайтом. Бот должен иметь возможность спокойно использовать django-orm и работать со всеми моделями всех приложений. Вариант с написанием API в Django и работа с ним из бота - не подходит.

Проблема в том, что первая библиотека асинхронная, а вот сама django - не совсем. У меня никак не получается связать всё это в одном проекте. Были попытки поиграться с asyncio, получить loop, передать его конструктору Bot, создавать новый и передать его, но всё это или совсем не работало, или работало, но не правильно. После чего удалось всё "адекватно" завести используя [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery). Я отправляю все callback-и в очередь, а таски получают их и отправляют в асинхронную функцию. Да, пример работает, но мне кажется это просто ужасный костыль, и ко всему прочему очень неудобный.

[image: Пример кода]

Один человек подсказал направление:

> Ты конечно можешь попробовать порыться в исходниках django/asgiref и найти как грамотно привязаться к главному лупу, и с ненулевой вероятностью это получится сделать, но в миллиард раз быстрее будет просто создать где-нибудь отдельный поток, в нем новый луп, и от него уже плясать

Но, к сожалению, для этого у меня ума не хватило. Сейчас нет желания продолжать делать проект с такой архитектурой, так как в это уже начинает оборачиваться головной болью, но другого выхода я к сожалению не вижу.

Случайно наткнулся на [django/channels](https://github.com/django/channels), но не понимаю, сможет оно мне помочь, или нет.

Буду безмерно благодарен любому, кто поможет выбраться из этой ужасной ямы.

Comment: проблема в том что джанга запускается и перезапускается постоянно и работает из нескольких процессов. тебе полюбому нужна шина. не целери так рэбит.

Comment: @eri Что вы имеете в виду? Celery как брокера у меня использует redis, но если поменять на rabbitmq разве что-то измениться? Код останется таким же. Может есть возможность из стороннего скрипта (не Django project или app) использовать её модели и ORM из неё? Или как-то получить основной loop запустив Django через ASGI?

Comment: Основной луп джанги не имеет применения. А орм можно использовать через менеджмент команду

Comment: @eri Очень интересное решение. И кажется он работает как нужно. Огромное вам спасибо.

Если вдруг кто-то столкнется с такой-же проблемой, вот [пример](https://pastebin.com/sEULgYsB) решения

Comment: @eri, кажется я поспешил с ответом. А как тогда работать с базой? Или я изначально вас не правильно понял? Любой запрос к бд кидает исключение SynchronousOnlyOperation, и sync_to_async не помогает.

Comment: синхронный бот не пойдет?

Comment: @eri пойдет, но хочется использовать эту либу, из-за большого кол-ва её плюшек. Даже если асинхронность останется только в названий.

Comment: есть минимальный пример как получить SynchronousOnlyOperation?

Comment: попробуй threadpoolexecutor

Answer (score 0):

Вообще лучший способ это не использовать джангу. А так можно разделить код, вынести орм (есть синк/асинк орм типа [encode/orm](https://github.com/encode/orm)) и уже импортировать её в веб фреймворк и бота. Засовывать бота в джангу очень плохая идея и делать так не надо.

Comment: В данном случае django тут используется ради своей админке, достоиных аналогов которой я не видел.

Но разве мне не придется тогда переопределять всю работу с бд? Если я использую не её родной orm. Просто я пока не нашел информаций по тому как этот модуль интегрируется в django, но буду пробывать.

Comment: найти бы орм с миграциями.)